# No visible @interface for 'class' declares the selector 'selector'

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm following "Learn Cocos2D" and in chapter 4 I'm met with the following directive:

And in the GameLayer init method, add the call to the initSpiders method discussed next, right after scheduleUpdate:

```
-(id) init {
if ((self=[super init])) {
...
       [self scheduleUpdate];
       [self initSpiders];
   }
   return self;
}
```

I get and ARC error message: no visible @interface for 'GameLayer' declares the selector 'initSpiders'

I get the same message at the line:  self resetSpiders

what am i missing? everything builds and runs great up to that point.

Comment: Have you written the methods for `initSpiders` and `resetSpiders` yet? The line "discussed next" implies that you are about to write these methods.

Answer (score 0):

This issue derives from the fact that the `initSpiders` and `resetSpiders` are not declared in your class interface and are defined in the `.m` file after the point where they are used.

If they are not missing altogether, you can fix this in either of 2 ways:

1. move the definition of the `initSpiders` and `resetSpiders` methods above your `init` method and the errors will disappear;
2. add a declaration for both methods in the `@interface` of the class.

(If you do both, it will also work)

Check your code to see if the implementation for those methods is available.

Comment: If using XCode 4.3+ this won't be the problem. This warning doesn't show for that cause anymore.

Comment: @sergio - i have included the .h file declarations as directed in the book:

Comment: @brentg: could it be possible that you are trying to compile too early? I mean, have you already found the `initSpiders` and `resetSpiders` implementations in the book and pasted them into your source files?

Answer (score 0):

Your error appears to be that you haven't followed the next bit of the book too. Completing the next section should allow you to compile your code without warnings like this.

A more complete extract of that section of the book is:

> And in the GameScene `init` method add the call to the `initSpiders` method discussed  next, right after `scheduleUpdate:`

```
-(id) init  { 
    if ((self = [super init])) 
    { 
        … 96  CHAPTER 4:  Your First Game 
        [self scheduleUpdate]; 
        [self initSpiders]; 
    } 
    return self;  
}
```

> After that a fair bit of code is added to the `GameScene` class, beginning with the  `initSpiders` method in Listing 4–8, which is creating the spider sprites.
>
> **Listing 4–8.** *For Easier Access, Spider Sprites Are Initialized and Added to a CCArray*

```
-(void) initSpiders 
{ 
    CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize]; 
    // using a temporary spider sprite is the easiest way to get the image's size 
    CCSprite* tempSpider = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spider.png"]; 
    float imageWidth = [tempSpider texture].contentSize.width; 
    // Use as many spiders as can fit next to each other over the whole screen width. 
    int numSpiders = screenSize.width / imageWidth; 
    // Initialize the spiders array using alloc. 
    spiders = [[CCArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numSpiders]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < numSpiders; i++) 
    { 
        CCSprite* spider = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"spider.png"]; 
        [self addChild:spider z:0 tag:2]; 
                 
        // Also add the spider to the spiders array. 
        [spiders addObject:spider]; 
    } 
    // call the method to reposition all spiders 
    [self resetSpiders]; 
}
```

Comment: interesting.  i copied a pasted your code for defining the init method and replace what i had.  I changed your [[CCArray alloc] initWithCapacity:numSpiders] with the NSMutableArray as it is declared in the .h file.  the error message disappeared for the [self initSpiders] but the error is still there for the [self resetSpiders] call.

Comment: This isn't my code.. this is a quote of the very next bit of the book. (Second edition)